# javascript replace single quote with double single quote issue

Tags: javascript

I have used below syntzx to replace single quote with double single quote issue

```
str.replace(/'/g,"''");
```

but it's replace everytime when it load page. like

I have text

" Test's and test's page and test's event"

then first time ,it will be

" Test''s and test''s page and test''s event"

then again

" Test'''s and test'''s page and test'''s event"

then next loading

" Test''''s and test''''s page and test''''s event"

can you please help to get just single to double single quote only?

Comment: Why are you replacing it multiple times to begin with?

Comment: you could use the html code equivalents, instead of the actual character. So use `&quot;` instead of `"` for example. Click [here](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php) for a reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's safe to assume that there won't be three or more quotes in a row, try this:

```
str.replace(/'+/g,"''")
```

If the assumption is not safe, and you just want to replace "a quote by itself" with two quotes, leaving multi-quotes alone, try this:

```
str.replace(/''?('*)/g,"''$1");
```

That being said, you might want to look into why it's replacing more than once in the first place ;)